# Unix - Find command with tar and gz works well from command line but not working on Script

Tags: unix

When i use this command on command line with hard coded values for the parameters $dir,$year,$month it works very well and creates the gzip file. I checked the contents of the gz file and i see the desired results.

```
find $dir -name '*_$year-$month-*' -type f -print | \
xargs tar -zvcf $dir/log.$year-$month.tar.gz
```

But when i embed this in a shell script and run, it won't run and gives me this error.

`tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your one-liner is full of quoting issues:

- `$dir` will break if the directory name contains whitespace. You need `"$dir"` instead
- Single quotes prevent variable expansion - `'*_$year-$month-*'` should probably be `"*_$year-$month-*"`.

  In your shell script code, `find` will not match any files (you don't have any filenames with the string `_$year-$month-`, do you?) and therefore `tar` will not be supplied with any files to include in the archive.

On a sidenote, using `xargs` in this particular case is dangerous - if you have too many files, `xargs` will call `tar` more than once and any files archived in all but the last run will be erased from the archive as it is overwritten.

Additionally, this command will also break on file paths with whitespace - by default `xargs` uses whitespace as the argument delimiter. Depending on the version of `find` and `xargs` binaries that you are using, there may be a `-print0` option for find and a matching `-0` option for `xargs` to deal with this issue:

```
find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...
```

Finally, some `xargs` versions have an option to avoid calling the specified command if no arguments have been supplied - for GNU `xargs` that is the `-r` option:

```
find ... -print0 | xargs -0 -r ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable substitution doesn't happen within single quotes.

Use double quotes: `find "$dir" -name "*_$year-$month-*" ...`

(You may use different kinds of quotes within the same argument if it's needed (not here): `'*_'"$year"`)

Answer (score 0):

If you can, attempt to `echo` the values of `$dir`, `$year`, `$month` from the shellscript onto the console. It is possible that those values are different in the shellscript.

Secodly, which `find` and `tar` is the shellscript using? Attempt to use the full paths for diagnostics or modify the value of `$PATH` to match what you get when you run the command from the command line.